# Resize image before loading - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm using [this plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugins-For-Simple-Image-Gallery-with-Magnifying-Glass-Effect.html)  to create image zoom and gallery, yet I want to scale all images  to fit with the container (using ratio algorithm).

Here is ratio function :

```
function scaleSize(maxW, maxH, currW, currH){
  var ratio = currH / currW;
  if(currW >= maxW && ratio <= 1){
     currW = maxW;
     currH = currW * ratio;
  } else if(currH >= maxH){
     currH = maxH;
     currW = currH / ratio;
  }
  return [currW, currH];
}
```

And this is how the gallery load images :

```
 var img = $('<img>').load(function(){
            img.appendTo(a);
            image_container.html(a);
 }).attr('src', src).addClass(opts.big_image_class);
```

What I've tried :

```
 var newSize = scaleSize(300, 320, $(".simpleLens-big-image").width(), $(".simpleLens-big-image").height());
 var img = $('<img>').load(function(){
            img.appendTo(a);
            image_container.html(a);
 }).attr('src', src).addClass(opts.big_image_class).width(newSize[0]).height(newSize[1]);
```

But `scaleSize` is not working properly since the current width and height is not yet defined (image not yet exist in dom).

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Where is your `.simpleLens-big-image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look into plugin code and think you call your `scaleSize()` too early. An image with class `simpleLens-big-image` exists first after var img is set up and `addClass()` is done.
Try following:

```
var img = $('<img>').load(function(){
           img.appendTo(a);
           image_container.html(a);
}).attr('src', src).addClass(opts.big_image_class);
// at this point img should contain $(".simpleLens-big-image") so we can refer to img
var newSize = scaleSize(300, 320, img[0].naturalWidth, img[0].naturalHeight());
img.width(newSize[0]).height(newSize[1]);
```

Comment: `console.log(img.width());` is 0, I think image was already loaded before calling its width. That is the problem.

Comment: @Nothing  If you like, please post result of `console.log(img[0].naturalWidth)`.

Comment: Well! there it is! It worked like a charm! Thanks Martin Ernst, you saved my day!

Comment: @Nothing  I'm glad, but I cannot guarantee that every old browser sets the `naturalWidth/Height` properties on an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and call the onload method. This will make sure that the image is loaded to the DOM before you resize

```
var img = $('<img>');    
img.src = src ;
img.onload = function() {
    // Run onload code.
} ;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Changing `load()` to `onload()` it makes the gallery stop working while hovering mouse on each image. I hope you don't mind to have a look, https://github.com/WitTrue/jQuery-SimpleLens/blob/master/src/jquery.simpleGallery.js here the script of the plugin and I'm editing it.